# Kotlin. Empty return for function without a return value

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have this following function.

```
    private val onConnect = Emitter.Listener {
    if(fromReconnect) {
        return
    }
    Log.d("Socket", "Socket Connected")
    val hndlr = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    hndlr.post{ Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Socket Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
    if (isTryLogin){
        reLogin()
    }
}
```

I am trying to return from the function if **fromReconnect** flag is set. But Android Studio is throwing **return not allowed here** error. But when I change **return** to **return@Listener** it's working fine.The IDE hints it's an **anonymous function**. Why do we need to **return@Listener** this instead of just **return**?

Comment: Related [Kotlin: Whats does “return@” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160489/kotlin-whats-does-return-mean)

Comment: @NileshRathod, Thanks. I could understand the need for **@** in nested functions & loops. For non-return functions, why do we need that? Even in that post, there's no answer for that. Do you mind to give some explanation?

Comment: here is your answer my friend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845729/kotlin-setonclicklistener

Comment: @NileshRathod. Thank you..Interesting finding for me today :)

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin allows non-local return only inside **inline** functions.
If your function is not marked as inline, or lambda parameter is marked **noinline** or **crossinline** than you cannot use the return statement, only return with a label. Because of non-local return - returns from caller function and not from lambda exactly.

You can find additional inforamtion in the documentation. 
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html